# How to make an Android launcher icon

Tags: java, android, icons, launching-application

The first impression of an app is the launcher icon in the app store so it is something that should not be taken lightly.  I have finally made it to the end of my first app but still need an icon.  I am not great in graphics or design.

My question is how do I go about either finding, creating or getting someone to offer a free service on making one.  I am not looking to spend money on a simple icon and I do not have access to Photoshop.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [Android Asset Studio](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/) is a good place to start. You can try your hand at making an icon from one of the pre-defined modes and it gives you icons for all screen densities. You can also go to the android design community in google plus and try asking for some help over there.

Comment: For downloading the .zip file .. it wouldn't work from safari.  In chrome it worked .. makes sense though, right ;).  Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Also if you want to create a logo there's a few free tools out there. Just search free logo makers. Here is one I like: https://www.logaster.com/